# JavaScript blocking CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a set of buttons that, when moused over, change color. The CSS for these runs this way:

```css
#navsite ul li button
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D);
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px 2px #888888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: 359ABC;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#navsite ul li button:hover
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #00054C;
    box-shadow:  2px 3px 3px 2px #888888;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: 359ABC;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Then, JavaScript changes the color on click (the example below covers one of five buttons, and there is a function for each button, forgive the bulk):

```
function dude()
{
    document.getElementById("dude").hidden=false;
    document.getElementById("bob").hidden=true;
    document.getElementById("ted").hidden=true;
    document.getElementById("joe").hidden=true;
    document.getElementById("fred").hidden=true;
    document.getElementById("button1").style.background='#00054C';
    document.getElementById("button2").style.background='-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D)';
    document.getElementById("button3").style.background='-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D)';
    document.getElementById("button4").style.background='-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D)';
    document.getElementById("button5").style.background='-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D)';
}
```

My problem now is that after this script has been activated, the CSS rule `#navsite ul li button:hover` no longer applies, and there is no mouseover effect at all. How do I fix the script so that it doesn't stop the CSS from running properly?

EDIT: Should I be considering converting that CSS clause to a part of the script itself? I've found it impossible to convert the script to CSS clauses, and I'd like to have minimal resources going on.

---

I've changed the script so that it lists active and inactive classes instead of listing the colors themselves. Its still rather bulky, though; any ideas on how to condense it?

Comment: That code looks like you have the same thing copy and pasted mutliple times to change different buttons, there are more efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: You're setting bakground-color and background-image in the CSS, but background in the script. Perhaps try altering the script to set style.backgroundImage and style.backgroundColor instead?

Comment: Remember, styling that comes from JS is entered inline, which has a higher priorty number than that of a stylesheet.

Comment: By the way, a lot of your CSS in the example above is not necessary. A #navsite ul li button:hover is still a #navsite ul li button, so you don't need to repeat all the properties that aren't changing. In your example only the background-image and background-color properties are required in the :hover bit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the styling directly to the element usign javascript, instead create a class .active and append that to clicked elements. Then remove the class when not active any more.

```
.active{-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, black, #4D4D4D)}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be considering converting that CSS clause to a part of the script itself?

No. Put away the presentation from the behaviour.

> I've found it impossible to convert the script to CSS clauses

No. Use classes in your CSS, you can dynamically change them with JavaScript:

```
button.active, button:hover {
    background: #00054C;
    /* forget about all the other properties, they are inherited!
    You know what the "C" in "CSS" stands for? */
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("button1").className = "active";
```

BTW, I guess you should not use the [`hidden` property](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute), which is not supported by IE, to hide your content. Use inline styles instead:

```
document.getElementById("dude").style.display = "none";
```